# Update a collection by inserting a new document into the embedded documents and fetch the Id of added document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following class diagram

```
  public class Blog
{
    public Guid BlogId { get; set; }

    public string BlogName { get; set; }

    public List<DiscussionPanel> DiscussionPanel { get; set; }

    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class DiscussionPanel
{
    public Guid DiscussionPanelId { get; set; }

    public string DiscussionPanelName { get; set; }

    public Guid CommentId { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public Guid CommentId { get; set; }

    public string CommentDesc { get; set; }
}
```

The very first time, I will create a Blog collection with DiscussionPanel and Comments as an empty list. When the user enters a comment under a discussion panel, the Comments will be updated in the embedded document 'Comments' and I have to fetch the inserted Id for the comment and stored into the Discussion panel collection. I am working with MongoDB c# driver. How could I achieve this?

I can insert the comment into the inner document using `Update.Push` command. But I am not able to fetch the Id of inserted document.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an `ObjectId` and assign it to the new `comment`:

```
public static ObjectId AddComment(ObjectId blogId)
{
    var comment = new Comment
    {
        Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(),
        CommentDesc = "My comment description"
    };
    var context = new Context();
    var builder = Builders<Blog>.Filter;
    var filter = builder.Eq(x => x.Id, blogId);
    var update = Builders<Blog>.Update
        .Push(x => x.Comments, comment);
    var updateResult = context.Blog.UpdateOne(filter, update);
    return comment.Id;
}
```

You can also get the number of modified documents to make sure that the comment is inserted:

```
var modified = updateResult.ModifiedCount;
if (modified != 0)
{
    // something was updated
}
```